# Can JXPath find objects by type?

Tags: java, jxpath

I have a relatively complicated object graph. Is it possible to have an expression in JXPath that will find any objects by type?

For example:

```
List<ThingToFind> myList = JXPathContext.newContext(rootObject).getValue(??objects of type ThingToFind??)
```

The List would then contain objects located at the paths:

```
/rootObject/foo/bar/instanceOfThingToFind
/rootObject/some/long/path/anotherInstanceOfThingToFind
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to do the same, I don't test it but you can try some this :

```
//class[@name='classname']/..
```